# Wordpress - how to print current tag page results?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to create an recursive Loop to display my tag.php Wordpress template look cool.

for example - i got tag name "Sports".

I want to split the results to be shown by categories.

Like this:

**Cavs news**

- First post
- Second Post
- Third post

**OKC news**

- First post
- Second post
- Third post

how can i do that?

thanks so much.

Comment: i tried to comment here but its too long

Answer (score 0):

mx0:

actually i know how to print but only in one category it looks like this:

```
        <div class="row main-row main-row-first">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Category Section -->
            <section class="search-section post">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- Category Title -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="post-header">
                            <h2 class="post-title extra-big">Cavs News</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Category Title -->


                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">

                        <?php
                        /* Start the Loop */
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        ?>

                        <!-- Category Post -->
                        <article class="search-section-item news-post">
                            <a href="#">
                                <header class="news-post-header">
                                    <h1 class="news-post-title red"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                    <span class="news-post-meta"><?php the_date('d.m.Y') ?> / <?php the_author() ?></span>
                                </header>
                                <div class="news-post-content">
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_field('intro'), 0, 100, '...' ) ?> <i class="readmore-icon"></i>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- Category Section -->


        </div><!-- end .container -->
    </div>
```

i know my code should begin in the title first, but i don't know how